# Removing everything from the taglist

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, tags

I'm trying to understand the necessity to delete everything from the array in the last string.

The task is: 
Find the link at position 18 (the first name is 1). Follow that link. Repeat this process 7 times. The answer is the last name that you retrieve.

```
    #Position / count - 3 variant
import urllib.request, urllib.parse, urllib.error
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import ssl
# Ignore SSL certificate errors
ctx = ssl.create_default_context()
ctx.check_hostname = False
ctx.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_NONE

taglist=list()
url=input("Enter URL: ")
count=int(input("Enter count:"))
position=int(input("Enter position:"))
for i in range(count):
    html = urllib.request.urlopen(url, context=ctx).read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
    tags=soup('a')
    for tag in tags:
        taglist.append(tag)
    url = taglist[position-1].get('href', None)
    del taglist[:]
print ("Retrieving:",url)
```

Answer (score 1):

Although that isn't the way I would do it, this is so you start with a new `taglist` every time. In this line:

```
for tag in tags:
    taglist.append(tag)
```

you append to the `taglist`. If you delete the content of the list, you will start fresh each iteration of the outer for loop.

The function would act differently when you index into the `taglist` if you had all the tags in there from the previous iterations. The key lines to look at for this are:

```
position=int(input("Enter position:"))
```

and

```
url = taglist[position-1].get('href', None)
```

If you didn't reset the `taglist`, `position-1` would correspond to a different element.

---

I'm not sure I would say what you did is *wrong*, but without actually knowing about the site you are using this for, I would be inclined to use a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions). The second way seems more Pythonic to me, and I also think it's more efficient.

```
# Instead of this
tags=soup('a')
for tag in tags:
    taglist.append(tag)
url = taglist[position-1].get('href', None)
del taglist[:]

# I would use this:
taglist = [tag for tag in soup('a')]
url = taglist[position-1].get('href', None)
```

Comment: Thank you, got it. How would you do this?

Comment: @MariaLavrovskaya See addition in answer